# Error in passing and modifying a array to a function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
void retsom(char **page)
{
    *page = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    *page[0] = 'a';
    *page[1] = 'b';
}
void main()
{
    char *page = NULL;
    retsom(&page);
    printf("%c %c",page[0],page[1]);

}
```

This code is giving segmentation fault. Its gives segmentation fault at *page[1] = 'b';

I want to pass a array to function and modify its content.

Comment: Sorry, silly mistake. Got the error. I have to change *page[0] = 'a' to (*page)[0] = 'a'. Seems like associativity issue.

Comment: Whenever you are unsure, you should look up the C Operator precedence, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Comment: @saurabhagarwal ,Post that as an answer.

Comment: The page is uninitialized, you set the first 2 bytes, but do not add a final `'\0'`. It would be safer to use `*page = calloc(10, sizeof **page);`

Comment: There is no advantage in defining `retsom` to take a pointer to a pointer to `char`.  It would be much simpler to use `char *retsom(void)`

Comment: @chqrlie +1 for calloc suggestion. I googed it and end up searching heartbleed vulnerability of OpenSSL.

Comment: @chqrlie . What do mean by page is uninitialized. You mean page in main() function? I passed the address of pointer in retsom() function and there I allocated the memory. isn't this correct ?

Comment: `retsom` allocates 10 chars with `malloc`.  These chars are uninitialized and may contain random values.  `retsom` only initializes the first 2 chars to `'a'` and `'b'`, leaving the rest in a random state.  This is error prone, leading to spurious, non reproducible bugs.  The cost of `calloc` versus `malloc` is negligible.  The benefit is the initialization to 0 of the allocated memory block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're regularly going to come across problems like this if you confuse yourself with too much indirection. Much better is to change to:

```
void retsom(char ** page)
{
    char * newpage = malloc(10);
    if ( !newpage ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newpage[0] = 'a';
    newpage[1] = 'b';

    *page = newpage;
}
```

and avoid the issue entirely. This also has the benefit that if you want to do something other than terminate in the event of `malloc()` or other failure, you haven't yet overwritten the pointer the caller supplied, so your function is better behaved in exceptional conditions.

Note that `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition, and therefore redundant, and that you shouldn't cast the return from `malloc()` in C. `malloc()` can also fail, so you should check its return value.